# closing a window opened with javascript after the request has sent

Tags: javascript, angular, same-origin-policy

Is there a way to close a window on load when opening a url in a new window with javascript (to a different origin)?

The following works fine:

```
var callWindow = $window.open("http://myexternalsite/?stuff=blah", "_blank");
callWindow.close();
```

but obviously it closes the window before the request to `http://myexternalsite/?stuff=blah` has sent. I don't care about getting a response back, only ensuring that the request completes.

I can't add the `window.close()` event to the response page because that's not the script that opened it... so seemingly all I'm left with is a manual timeout and hope it completes in time.

I also can't just do this as a simple http request because the site runs on https and the call is to an (internal network) server that does not have an ssl certificate.

Comment: why you don't make AJAX get request to the given URL, you can handle all the result states and it is much better approach

Comment: Why you don't switch to an AJAX request to your URL? Btw did you try to add an `onload` event to that new window?
`callWindow.onload = function() { callWindow.close(); };`

Comment: I can't make an AJAX request because the browser will complain about mixed content types (the site is on https, the local page link is http only)

Comment: I did try setting `callWindow.onload` but it never appears to get called. I assume it  gets overwritten by the response page

Comment: have you tried to send the request in a hidden iframe ?

Comment: @ron I would assume that's blocked by most browsers too as active mixed content?

Comment: @PeteTinkler i dont think it is blocked, the problem appears if you used to get or set data from iframe content to the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the page in the window you're opening tell your page that it has loaded. The best way to do this is to use `postMessage`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

First, your page needs to start listening for messages:

```
window.addEventListener("message", messagelistener);
```

Second, the page you're loading in the new window has to post a message to its opener (your page):

```
window.opener.postMessage(message, targetOrigin);
```

`targetOrigin` is a string that must match the host of your page (protocol + hostname + port)

You need to create the `messageListener` event handler function. In this you should verify that `event.origin` is the page you opened so that this message is actually from that page.

The `message` you send from the opened page can be used to verify that everything went OK or not, or you can send whatever and in your `messageListener` just assume that any message from the opened page meant it loaded OK.

If you in your `messageListener` function determine that the opened page has verified that it should be closed, you close it.